# Create Web project for ASP pages in Interdev

Tags: visual-studio, asp-classic

How to create a web project in Visual Interdev for ASP pages. I need to debug the ASP pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug classic ASP pages by opening your web site in Visual Studio 2005 or Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (won't work with plain VStudio 2008).

You have to manually attach to the dllhost process to start a debugging session.

Comment: I got it with existing projects

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a couple of issues with that last time I tried to set it up.  This was to do with the versions of DLLs used.  I had to replace a couple with newer versions.  I need to reinstall, so will update this when I find out